# Find Latest Folder in a Path that starts with a Certain word

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to ask if it's possible to find the latest folder in a path that starts with a pattern.

Example, let's say we are in this path: `C:\Users\user`

There are 4 folders (and many other that we don't care about) that have names:

```
folder13, folder15, folder17, folder20
```

How can I return that the latest folder's number is `20` with Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First generate a list of files and folders using `os.listdir()`. Then filter it so it only contains folders. Next use `sorted()` to sort the entries based on any numerical values contained in the names. Lastly, take the last entry in the sorted list to get the one with the largest number:

```
import os
import re

folders = [folder for folder in os.listdir(r'C:\Users\user') if os.path.isdir(folder)]
folders = sorted(folders, key=lambda x: [int(v) if len(v) else -1 for v in re.findall('(\d+)', x)])

print(folders[-1])
```

This approach would work when there happens to be multiple levels of numbers, so for example a folder called `Folder20_1` would be sorted as `(20, 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

First you can use the [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.html#os.walk) function to parse all sub folders from a specified root folder (recursively) or [os.listdir](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.html#os.listdir) to get a list containing the names of the entries in the directory.

Next you can use the [re](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html) module, it provides some functions to use the regular expressions.

Here an example:

```
rootPath = "C:\\Users\\user"
pattern = re.compile(r"^.+[^\d](\d+)$")
latestFolderNumber = 0
dirs = [entry for entry in os.listdir(rootPath) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(rootPath, entry))]
for name in dirs:

     match = pattern.match(name)
     if match:
          latestFolderNumber = int(match.group(1))


print("The latest number is " + latestFolderNumber)
```

This website may help you to test your regular expressions before implementation: https://regex101.com/